# Search database through Views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I m trying to search database values through the views.

I m stuck at the below error.

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO

--EXEC Customer.sp_FindInViews Stephen, Sales

ALTER PROCEDURE Customer.sp_FindInViews @stringToFind VARCHAR(100), @schema sysname
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE   
      @ViewName AS nVarChar(128)
      , @TmpQuery AS nVarChar(500)
      , @Out3 as int

    , @sqlCommand VARCHAR(8000)
    , @where VARCHAR(8000)
    , @columnName sysname
    , @cursor VARCHAR(8000)

DECLARE Outer_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT schema_name(schema_id)+'.'+name as "View_Name",schema_id FROM [sys].[all_views] 
    where schema_id  in (@schema)

    OPEN Cur_Views
        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Views INTO @ViewName
        WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @ViewName + ' WHERE'
            SET @where = ''

        DECLARE col_cursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT syscolumns.name FROM sys.sysobjects "sysobjects"
            INNER JOIN sys.syscolumns "syscolumns"
            on syscolumns.id = sysobjects.id
            WHERE (sysobjects.type = 'V'    and SCHEMA_NAME(sysobjects.uid) + '.' +sysobjects.name = @ViewName)

            OPEN col_cursor   
                FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor INTO @columnName   
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
                BEGIN   
                    IF @where <> ''
                        SET @where = @where + ' OR'
                        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        SET @where = @where + ' ' + @columnName + ' LIKE ''' + @stringToFind + ''''
                        SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand +   @where

                        CREATE TABLE #Data (var varchar)
                        SELECT  @TmpQuery = @sqlCommand
                        INSERT #Data exec (@TmpQuery)
                        SELECT @Out3 = var from #Data
                        PRINT @Out3
                        DROP TABLE #Data
                    FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor INTO   @columnName   
                END   
            CLOSE col_cursor   
            DEALLOCATE col_cursor       
    CLOSE Outer_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE Outer_Cursor             
END
GO
```

The code compiles , but it does give the error when executed as below :
    EXEC Customer.sp_FindInViews Stephen, Sales

```
Msg 16915, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_FindInViews, Line 19
A cursor with the name 'Outer_Cursor' already exists.
Msg 16905, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_FindInViews, Line 22
The cursor is already open.
Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_FindInViews, Line 23
Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.
```

I m not sure , why I m getting this error. I feel i m handling them. Any input on this , would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Did I mention How much I detest cursors?!?  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me that you've changed cursor names. You start by declaring Outer_Cursor then open a cursor called Cur_Views.

Also when you fetch from the cursor you are only putting the cursor values in to 1 variable, in the cursor declaration you list 2 fields (View_Name and schema_id).

```
DECLARE Outer_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT schema_name(schema_id)+'.'+name as "View_Name",schema_id FROM [sys].[all_views]  
    where schema_id  in (@schema) 

    OPEN Cur_Views
       FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Views INTO @ViewName
```

The "cursor is already open" errors occur when you run the procedure a second time becuase the original cursors are still open (as the first attempt errored before being able to close them).

Comment: Yes , that indeed solved my errors about the cursors .... but not purpose.... thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the answer you've been looking for, but SQLSearch (http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) is an excellent tool for searching databases (of course, you can set it to search views only) and it's free...

Comment: Yes , similar to that ... but i still wanted to get a SQL solution for that ... Thanks !!!